# PHP4 supports DOMDocument? My code says yes?

Tags: php

When I check phpinfo(), I see /usr/local/php4/lib/php.ini

That means PHP4, right?

But When I execute the line of code below, it returns PHP5. WTF? I thought PHP4 did not have the DOMDocument class. I need to test for PHP4 and do a workaround, but this specific test is confusing me. Is there another more foolproof way to check for PHP4 in script?

```
if (is_admin() && class_exists('DOMDocument')) {
    echo "PHP5";
} else {
    echo "Awe PHP4";
}
```

Comment: Try `if (PHP_VERSION < 5)` then. The DomDocument under PHP4.4 is probably http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.domxml.php

Comment: DOMDocument does not exist in PHP4, _but_ I could do `class DOMDocument {}` in PHP4, and now the check fails.

Comment: @mario > BINGO!!! PHP_VERSION returns 4.49 so your test is the ticket. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of your PHP is listed right on top of any `phpinfo()` output. You can also determine it by echoing `phpversion()` or from CLI with `php -v`.

Apart from that, no. PHP4 does not support [`DOMDocument`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.construct.php) (at least not the one you are refering to). The [old DOM XML extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.domxml.php) has a similar named class though.

Try the following:

```
echo extension_loaded('domxml') ? 'old' : 'new';
```

Comment: Its version 4.4.9, which apparently supports DOMDocument class, so that was not a reliable test. If(PHP_VERSION < 5) is much better. Thanks!

Comment: @Scott it doesnt support DOM's DOMDocument class. It supports DOM XML's DOMDocument class. That's a difference. Their APIs are not the same. `extension_loaded` let's you check which of the two it is.

Answer (score 0):

phpinfo() is a cool function :)

edit, lots of similar functions here
http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.info.php

you seem like you'd be interested in
phpversion() and version_compare()

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to check your PHP version from `phpinfo()` is to read the header at the very top, but when doing checks in PHP code, checking [`php_version()`](https://www.php.net/php_version) is the way to do. There is also a predefined constant `PHP_VERSION`.

Answer (score 0):

Well if phpinfo says you run php5 you are running php5. assuming by php_info you mean phpinfo.

you may wanna check the function [phpversion](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpversion.php)

The path you are referring to is just the configured config file which could be anything.

You probably updated and kept it ages ago.